# How do I set option variables for a colorscheme in vim?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

The [vim-lucius](https://github.com/jonathanfilip/vim-lucius) colorscheme provides several presets and a couple options that can be customized.

I cannot figure out how to override the preset background color to leave it as transparent/none. According to the documentation:

```
g:lucius_no_term_bg (default: 0)

Setting this will cause the color scheme to not set a background color 
in the terminal (useful for transparency or terminals with different 
background colors).
```

This is exactly what I want to accomplish. I tried adding `let g:lucius_no_term_bg = 0` to my .vimrc but nothing happens and the background remains dark. Should I be setting these options directly in the lucius.vim file or in my .vimrc?

I have `set t_Co=256` enabled. I'm using Terminal on Mac OS X 10.9.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command is right, and as long as you put this *before* the `:colorscheme lucius` command in your `~/.vimrc`, it should be considered by the scheme.

You may be struggling with the negative configuration option (which is best avoided): To *prevent* setting the background, you need to *enable* the option (with a value != 0):

```
let g:lucius_no_term_bg = 1
```

As it stands, you're just setting the default (`0`), which does set the background.